# How to update data with ElasticSearch resolver in AWS AppSync

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-appsync

I'm trying to update existing value in AppSync with ElasticSearch resolver. Here is how to update existing data with ElasticSearch resolver. But whenever I run that code, found error message.

```
{
    "version":"2017-02-28",
    "operation":"POST",
    "path":"/mydata/logs/_update/$context.arguments.input.id",
    "params":{
        "headers":{},
        "queryString":{},
        "body":{
            "script": {
                "params" : {
                    "read": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Error: GraphQL error: Elasticsearch responded with an error: Bad
>   Request

But I tried with PUT method, existing columns are moved and only `read: true` column added.

```
{
    "version":"2017-02-28",
    "operation":"PUT",
    "path":"/mydata/logs/$context.arguments.input.id",
    "params":{
        "headers":{},
        "queryString":{},
        "body":{
            "read": true
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through the same error. I think one of the issues is with the path. You are accessing the input id dynamically. should we something similar to this
"/mydata/logs/${context.arguments.input.id}/_update". Let me know if you are still facing the issue.

```
{
    "version":"2017-02-28",
    "operation":"POST",
    "path":"/mydata/logs/${context.arguments.input.id}/_update",
    "params":{
        "headers":{},
        "queryString":{},
        "body":{
            "script": {
                "params" : {
                    "read": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing ElasticSearch upsert operation via AppSync below is my code snippet for request.vtl.

```
#set($args=$ctx.args)
#set($id=$util.defaultIfNull($args.id, $util.autoId()))
#set($text=$args.text)
#set($searchContextInput=$args.searchContextInput)
#set($contextTypeList=$searchContextInput.contextType)
#set($contextId=$searchContextInput.contextId)
#set($ownerId=$ctx.identity.claims.get("custom:logicalId"))
#set($reqEndpoint="/recent/_doc/${id}/_update")
#set($now=$util.time.nowISO8601())
#set($meta={
  "contextId": $contextId,
  "contextType": $contextTypeList,
  "text": $text
})
#set($bodyReq={
  "script" : {
    "source": "if(ctx._source.meta==null){ ctx._source.meta=[];} ctx._source.meta.add(params.meta); ctx._source.modified=params.modified",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params" : {
      "meta": $meta,
      "modified": $now
    }
  },
  "upsert" : {
    "id" : $id,
    "meta": [$meta],
    "created": $now,
    "modified": $now
  }
})
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "POST",
  "path": $util.toJson($reqEndpoint),
  "params": {
    "body": $util.toJson($bodyReq)
  }
}
```